# Selenium explicit waits not working by time.sleep working

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am a newbie for selenium. I am trying to refresh the page when the list has loaded. The HTML is like below.

```
<span class="" title="Refresh">
  <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary" tabindex="0" type="button">
    <span class="MuiButton-label">Refresh</span>
    <span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span>
  </button>
</span>
```

Based on this html, I decided to like below in selenium part.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Refresh']"))).click()
```

If I use it like this, I am getting the below error

```
  File "workspaces.py", line 47, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Refresh']"))).click()
  File "/home/assistanz/Projects/Python/selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/home/assistanz/Projects/Python/selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/home/assistanz/Projects/Python/selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/assistanz/Projects/Python/selenium/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <span class=""> is not clickable at point (1123,116) because another element <div class="MuiBackdrop-root jss29"> obscures it
```

But If I use like below the code is working fine

```
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='Refresh']").click()
```

I am not able to identify the differences. Based on my understanding, we should explicit wait concept not time.sleep

Could anyone help to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

See, this return a Web Element

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='Refresh']")
```

also, a equivalent web element return code with Explicit wait would look like this :

```
 WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Refresh']"))).click()
```

the only different between these two are :

1. `driver.find_element_by_xpath` will try to look immediately for the `xpath` node in the `DOM` where as `WebDriverWait` will look at an interval of `500ms` , if the element is found, return otherwise raise `Timeout Exception.`

also, See the impact of Implicit wait on `find_element` :

> By implicitly waiting, WebDriver polls the DOM for a certain duration
> when trying to find any element. This can be useful when certain
> elements on the webpage are not available immediately and need some
> time to load.

also

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
> amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
> not immediately available. The default setting is 0, meaning disabled.
> Once set, the implicit wait is set for the life of the session.

so if you do not have implicit wait then, `driver.find_element` **may often** result in `NoSuchElement` Exception.

Now, we will look for WebDriverWait which is also known as Explicit wait.

> The condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of
> the wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition
> returns a falsy value, it will keep trying and waiting.

also..

> Since explicit waits allow you to wait for a condition to occur, they
> make a good fit for synchronising the state between the browser and
> its DOM, and your WebDriver script.

Now `time.sleep()` is also an explicit wait but worst of it's kind.

Now coming to the actual question, it's really a strange the with Explicit wait, you are getting

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message:
> Element  is not clickable at point (1123,116) because
> another element  obscures it

Are you sure, if you are performing similar user interaction with Selenium in both cases ?

Also, I see a button:

So, I would suggest you to write xpath like this :

```
//span[text()='Refresh']/..
```

and try to use with both of them :-

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Refresh']/.."))).click()
```

and

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Refresh']/..").click()
```

and see if explicit waits helps or not.

Also, `time.sleep(5)` does not give you a guarantee that you'd never face the exception.

My recommendation again would be to have WebDriverWait for the previous code as well which should be written before this `WebDriverWait` code. Basically to have `WebDriverWait()` everywhere instead of `driver.find_element`

Answer (score 1):

The difference here is that

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Refresh']"))).click()
```

will click on that element exactly on the moment when this element becomes clickable.
This can, and often occurs, when the web page is still not fully rendered, so other element can be placed on the element we are trying to click or our targeted element is still not rendered to it's final position etc.
This is why you are facing `ElementClickInterceptedException` in this case.
On the other hand,

```
time.sleep(5)
```

makes a hardcoded pause of 5 seconds.
This will obviously be more than enough to render the entire page elements, so after that when you going to click on the element immediately with

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@title='Refresh']").click()
```

it will work correctly.
So, using the hardcoded sleeps like `time.sleep(5)` is not recommended since this normally will make your test run time significantly longer.
Also, sometimes when the internet connection is slow or server response takes too long time this will fail.
I would suggest combining both explicitly waits with short sleep.
In this case you will reduce the entire run time and also ensure you test working correctly.
Like this:

```
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@title='Refresh']")))
time.sleep(0.2)
button.click()
```

Here you are getting the point when the element is found clickable, then adding a short delay of 200 milliseconds to ensure the rest of the elements are finally rendered and then click the element.
You can also use other approaches, like clicking the element with JavaScript executer or scrolling to the element you are going to click. It depends on each test / page etc. specific details. But the above approach seems to me to be the simplest and reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the element that you want to click is not clickable. Also, instead of searching for span and clicking it, search for the button and then the class in the xpath:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary']")).click()
```

also u put one extra pair of brackets in the given line.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, multiple buttons are there. How do we identify that I am clicking the refresh button?

Comment: You can inspect the element using google’s console(if u are using google that is). You can search the element by id if it is present. This is because a class can be assigned to multiple buttons on a webpage, but an id is used to uniquely identify an HTML element